# Generic covariance with interfaces - Weird behavioural contradiction between "is" and "=" operators

Tags: c#, generics, interface, casting, covariance

I had a complete wtf moment when dealing with covariant interfaces.

Consider the following:

```
class Fruit { }
class Apple : Fruit { }

interface IBasket<out T> { }

class FruitBasket : IBasket<Fruit> { }
class AppleBasket : IBasket<Apple> { }
```

Note:

- `AppleBasket` **does not inherit from** `FruitBasket`.
- `IBasket` is **covariant**.

---

Later on in the script, you write:

```
FruitBasket fruitBasket = new FruitBasket();
AppleBasket appleBasket = new AppleBasket();

Log(fruitBasket is IBasket<Fruit>);
Log(appleBasket is IBasket<Apple>);
```

...and as you'd expect, the output is:

```
true
true
```

---

**HOWEVER**, consider the following code:

```
AppleBasket appleBasket = new AppleBasket();

Log(appleBasket is IBasket<Fruit>);
```

You'd expect it to output `true`, right? Well, you are **wrong** -- at least with my compiler anyway:

```
false
```

---

That's strange, but perhaps it's performing an **implicit conversion**, similar to converting an `int` to a `long`. An `int` is not a kind of `long`, but a long can be assigned the value of an int implicitly.

**HOWEVER**, consider this code:

```
IBasket<Fruit> basket = new AppleBasket(); // implicit conversion?

Log(basket is IBasket<Fruit>);
```

This code runs just fine - no compiler errors or exceptions - even though we previously learned that an `AppleBasket` is NOT a kind of `IBasket<Fruit>`. Unless there is some third option, it must be doing an implicit conversion in the assignment.

Surely `basket` - declared as an `IBasket<Fruit>` - **MUST** be an instance of `IBasket<Fruit>`... I mean, that's what it was declared as. Right?

But no, according to the `is` operator, **you're wrong again!** It outputs:

```
false
```

...Meaning `IBasket<Fruit> fruit` is NOT an instance of `IBasket<Fruit>`... Huh?

...Meaning the following property:

```
IBasket<Fruit> FruitBasket { get { ... } }
```

Can sometimes return something that **both isn't null**, and **isn't an instance of `IBasket<Fruit>`.**

---

**FURTHER**, ReSharper tells me that `appleBasket is IBasket<Fruit>` is redundant in that `appleBasket` is **always** of the provided type, and can be safely replaced with `appleBasket != null`... ReSharper got it wrong too?

So, what's going on here? Is this just my version of C# (Unity 5.3.1p4 - It's Unity's own branch of Mono, based off of .NET 2.0) being a nut?

Comment: Uh, what version of .NET are you running? `appleBasket is IBasket<Fruit>` prints `true` for me. See [the fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/aiNzDA) to replicate.

Comment: for me to it is working, even I'm interested to see which version of `.Net`.

Comment: The version of Mono provided in Unity 5.3.1p4 - It's Unity's own branch of Mono, based off of .NET 2.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your comments, it is no small surprise that covariance isn't properly being supported...it was added in C#4.

What **IS** incredibly surprising is that it is even compiling at all if it is targeting a port based off of .NET 2.0

Comment: Guess I'm off to Unity bug reporting land. Wish me luck!

Comment: That might be a long and uphill battle.  Hope it ends well for you :)

Comment: From Unity QA: "I managed to reproduce the issue. Fortunately, it was solved and is no longer reproducible with 5.5.0a4 version of Unity. Please, test the issue when Unity 5.5 will be publicly available and let me know if the issue is still present."

Comment: @Hatchling there you go!  Way to get it into a build!

Answer (score 0):

You're able to declare this for one reason:

```
IBasket<Fruit> basket = new AppleBasket();
```

Because this interface has no methods that reference `<T>`.

```
interface IBasket<out T> { }
```

There's nothing for the compiler to protect you from because you can only declare the types. You can't do anything with them. Try adding a method to the interface:

```
interface IBasket<out T>
{ 
    void Add(T item);
}
```

And that's where the compiler will raise an error, requiring that you remove the covariance (`out`) from the interface. If you remove it then this now won't compile:

```
IBasket<Fruit> basket = new AppleBasket()
```

because then you would be able to add non-`Apple` objects to an `IBasket<Apple>`.

Comment: Actually, declaring an OUTPUT method in IBasket has no effect on this behaviour.

For example: interface IBasket<out T> { T Item { get; } }

Declaring an method where T is taken as input (such as the one you provided) will generate an error, though. In which case, you'd need to use <in T>.